# Prettier configuration for JSX tag to be in one line

Tags: reactjs, jsx, prettier, prettier-vscode, prettier-standard

My JSX looks like this:
[image]

But I really want it to look this way:
[image]

Can anyone provide their react-prettier json

Answer (score -2):

Can you try hitting Option + Shift + F

Comment: I am trying to configure prettier.

Comment: @armaan https://github.com/prettier/eslint-plugin-prettier